# Save new workbooks keeping worksheet name after macro run

Tags: excel, vba, save

I am splitting a file by 15000 rows each. I am running a macro from a spreadsheet that asks for file selection and then split it. However, when I try to name the split files it cames with the active sheet name of the file where the macro is running rather than to the files split.

I have to split more than 10 files and I need to get the name changing without me writing it every time.

This is the code of the Script, could you please tweak it out to get the output I need?

I tried to find around the globe but never gotten the right example.

```
Sub Split_File()

Dim iCalc As Long, i As Long
Dim my_FileName As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbn As String

wbn = wb.ActiveSheet
iCalc = Application.Calculation

With Application

    .Calculation = xlManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False

End With

my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=my_FileName, ReadOnly:=False)

With wb.ActiveSheet

    For i = 2 To .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 15000

        Range(.Range("A1:BP1").Address(0, 0) & "," & .Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "BP").Resize(15000)).Address(0, 0)).Copy

            Workbooks.Add
            Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            With ActiveWorkbook
                .SaveAs Filename:="itsownfolder\" & wbn & "Rows" & i & ".xlsx"
                .Close
            End With
    Next i

End With

With Application

    .Calculation = iCalc
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: On this: `wbn = wb.ActiveSheet` it should return an error, because `wb` is not set. Did you meant to use something like: `wbn = ActiveSheet.Name` instead? Do realize that later on in your code you using this variable to create `FileName`

Comment: You are correct, it returns an error. But that should be the name I need. That is the name of the workbook I have opened and not the name of the one I have recorded the macro in. The latter is returned if I use the ActiveSheet.Name variable instead.

Comment: So without going through the rest of your code (might be more mishaps) but since you use a `With` statement, you could replace `wbn` with `.Name` in `.SaveAs Filename:="itsownfolder\" & wbn & "Rows" & i & ".xlsx"`

Comment: Thank you JvdV for your reply. When i set wbn = ActiveSheet.Name, It just spit out book2rowsxx, book3rowsxx, etc.

Comment: Hi JvdV, it still does not work it saves files as book1rows2, book2rows15002, book3rows30002, etc. it should get the name of the file or at least of active sheet.